# Cucumber step for light box content

Tags: cucumber, lightbox, fancybox

Is it possible to write cucumber scenario for data to be shown inside Lightbox (Fancybox) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you use a JavaScript-aware driver for Capybara, such as Selenium, Culerity or Celerity.